# How Can I post hierarchcal params my API using PAW-APP

Tags: paw-app

I want to post to a Rails API I'm building to create a record.  Usually with rails, the format would be

activity: {user_id: 3, category: 4}

How Can I post like this using PAW?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Place the params in json area, with the activity node as an object.

[image]